# How to install libboost-devel on CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm, boost

How to install libboost-devel on CentOS 6.3?

I have tried the following command:

```
yum install libboost-devel
```

Output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ellogroup.com
 * extras: mirror.ellogroup.com
 * updates: mirror.ellogroup.com
Setting up Install Process
No package libboost-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll want to install the `boost-devel` package.

Package description: **boost-devel.x86_64 : The Boost C++ headers and shared development libraries**

```
yum install boost-devel
```

Comment: Works perfectly on CentOS 7.3 x64 as well, many thanks! (April 21, 2017)